# Is a set of some $m \times n$ matrices a relation?

Tags: matrices, terminology, relations

A relation between  sets $A_i, i = 1, \dots, n$  is defined as a subset of $\prod_i A_i$.

Given $m, n \in \mathbb N$, is a set of (some or all) $m \times n$ matrices over $\mathbb R$ considered  a subset of $\mathbb R^{nm}$, and therefore  a relation on $\mathbb R$?

If yes, do we lose the fact that a $m \times n$ matrix is two dimensional, by treating it as a one dimensional $nm$ vector?

How can we not losing that fact, by considering a set of (some or all) $m \times n$ matrices not just as a relation  on $\mathbb R$, but as something more sophisticated? Thanks.

Note: I am ignoring the operations on the matrices and therefore any algebraic structure on the set of some matrices. just think a n by m matrix as a n by m array please.

Comment: You don't "lose" anything just by changing your point of view, so I don't see the problem.

Comment: No, because from $\mathbb R^{nm}$, you can't tell it is  two dimensional. A vector and a matrix are never the same.

Comment: While I see what you mean by "a matrix is two dimensional", that's a matter of how we think about them, it's not a precise mathematical quality, which makes the question hard if not impossible to answer.

Comment: To elaborate, you can endow $\mathbb R^{nm}$ with a ring structure in the obvious way that makes it isomorphic to the ring of $n \times m$ real matrices, so there's absolutely no algebraic loss of information.

Comment: Tim, what are your $A$ and $B$?

Comment: @ShawnO'Hare: The question in my post is: Is a set of some n×m real matric a relation or something more sophisicated?

Comment: @whacka: $A$ and $B$ are two arbitrary sets. see the definition of a relation.

Comment: @Shawn Your comment is misleading. There is no "the ring of $n\times m$ matrices" except in the special case when $n=m$. And I'm not sure what you mean by "in the obvious way"; for me that means the direct product structure, which certainly doesn't make it a matrix algebra. Tim: rings and relations having, like, nothing to do with each other. Do you know what a ring is?

Comment: I asked you what **your** $A$ and $B$ are. You asked if sets of matrices in $\Bbb R^{nm}$ can be relations. But what are the $A$ and $B$ for which these sets are subsets of $A\times B$? (Also, technical note, $\Bbb R^{nm}$ is not a set of matrices, $M_{n\times m}(\Bbb R)$ would be the notation for that.)

Comment: @whacka: The question in my post is: Is a set of some n×m real matrices a relation or something more sophisicated?  I haven't put any operation on the set of matrices yet, and the set can consist of any matrices or not.

Comment: Ah. If we think of matrices as elements of $\Bbb R^{nm}$ then you indeed have an $nm$-ary relation on $\Bbb R$ (I was stuck on thinking binary relations), trivially.

Comment: @whacka: See the first line i just updated in my post. So what is a set of matrices, something more sophisiticated than a nm-ary relation on $\mathbb R$? Thinking it as a nm-ary relation on $\mathbb R$, will lose the dimension and size of the matrices.

Comment: Yes, matrices are much, much more than just elements of a direct product. We can add and multiply matrices together, and scalar multiply as well, so this direct product is more than just a set, it's an algebra over a field. All of this algebraic structure is what allow us to do linear algebra, one of the most important subjects in all of mathematics.

Comment: I am now ignoring the operations on the matrices and therefore any algebraic structure on the set of some matrices, just think a n by m matrix as a n by m array please. @whacka

Comment: Hmm, okay. There are isomorphisms $\Bbb R^{nm}\cong M_{m\times n}(\Bbb R)$ (most set-theoretic maps will mangle things up, so let's just say it's one of the ones that send entries to coordinates), but given an element of $\Bbb R^{nm}$ we don't know which element of $M_{m\times n}(\Bbb R)$ it corresponds to without knowing what isomorphism is being used. So of course we lose information. This has nothing to do with relations, either.

Comment: @whacka Yes, I meant n=m.  My apologies for the typo.